# Should you defrag before capturing an image?

Tags: windows, image, sysprep, defrag, imagex

If I'm capturing an image with `imagex.exe /capture ...`, does it matter if I defrag the hard disk prior to doing so (or strictly speaking, before sysprep)?  Is there any benefit to doing so with a file-based imager like this?  Would there be any benefit to defragging after applying the image?

I am asking about defragging non-SSD drives.  I believe defragging an SSD is generally considered a no-no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to. `Imagex.exe` creates a WIM file which is a file-based disk image. It's not a disk clone so it won't take into account the way the disk space is used or where the free space is.

Same goes for applying the image to a machine - I doubt you would need to defrag.

On the flip side, defragging is definitely recommended when capturing block level images using Ghost or SCVMM P2V.